# Исключить одинаковые элементы списка

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть список all_users, в этом списке находятся словари - person, у person есть параметр под названием user_id. Я не хочу добавлять в список словари с одинаковыми user_id.

```
all_users = []
while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and not (event.from_me):
            person = dict.fromkeys(['user_id'])
            person['user_id'] = event.user_id
            all_users.append(person)
            for x in all_users:
                print(x)
```

Данный код присваивает id человека, который написал сообщение, в person как значение по ключу user_id, в дальнейшем, добавляя person в список all_users

```
            for it in all_users:
                if it['user_id'] != person['user_id']:
                    all_users.append(person)
                    print("Добавил!")
                else:
                print("Этот пользователь уже добавлен")
```

Добавив этот код перед тем, как я выводил на экран all_users, я думал, что в список перестанут добавляться person с одинаковыми user_id, но данный код не выполнялся вообще + перестал выполнялся вывод всего списка на экран.

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я выполняю проверку на совпадение user_id, если правильно, то почему перестает выполняться код? а если неправильно, то как можно выполнить реализацию по-другому?

```
all_users_ids = {user['user_id'] for user in all_users}
        if user_id not in all_users_ids:
            person = {'user_id': user_id, 'link': link}
            all_users.append(person)
            print("Добавил")
            for x in all_users:
                print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
all_users = []
while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and not (event.from_me):
            user_id = event.user_id
            # Просто подготовил отдельно набор всех айдишники пользователей
            # Для этого я использовал синтаксис set comprehension
            # (можете погуглить, что это такое)
            all_users_ids = {user['user_id'] for user in all_users}
            # Проверяю, содержится ли user_id
            # в заранее подготовленном наборе айдишников.
            # Ключевое слово in позволяет проверить наличие элемента
            # в списке или множестве без всякого цикла
            if user_id not in all_users_ids:
                # Просто создал словарь с ключом 'user_id'
                # И значением из переменной user_id
                # Это просто другой способ записи для
                # {'user_id': user_id}
                person = dict(user_id=user_id)
                all_users.append(person)
            for x in all_users:
                print(x)
```

По поводу вашего кода. Вот в этом куске

```
for it in all_users:
    if it['user_id'] != person['user_id']:
        all_users.append(person)
```

вы, видимо, хотите проверить, что пользователь с таким `user_id` не содержится в `all_users`. Но этот кусок кода не будет так работать. Вместо этого он проверяет, что в `user_id` есть отличающиеся элементы. А так как сначала у вас там нет вообще никаких элементов - ни отличающихся, ни совпадающих, то добавление вообще никогда не срабатывает.

И хорошо, что не срабатывает - потому что если бы у вас там уже были бы элементы, то он новый добавлял бы многократно - по числу уже имеющихся и список быстро бы начал раздуваться до неприличных размеров. (Если я ничего не путаю, тут был бы степенной рост, то есть уже через несколько десятков пользователей список съел бы у вас всю память в компьютере)

Comment: Большое спасибо, код работает, но не могли бы вы пояснить, что делает этот кусок кода? с 6 по 8 строку

Comment: И еще вопрос. Код прикрепил вверху. При первой итерации добавляется пользователь, выводится надпись "добавил" и выводится весь список all_users, при дальнейших итерациях надпись "добавил" не выводится в консоль и person не добавляется в all_users, но выводится весь список all_users. Это как? все написано в одном условии, почему одни строки выполняются, а другие нет?

Comment: @Дима, я дописал в мой код комментарии с объяснениями

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял:

```
all_users = []
listID = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5 ]

for i in listID:
    if {'user_id': i} in all_users:
        print("Этот пользователь уже добавлен")
    else:
        all_users.append({'user_id': i})
        print("Добавил!")


Добавил!
Добавил!
Добавил!
Добавил!
Этот пользователь уже добавлен
Этот пользователь уже добавлен
Добавил!

print(all_users)
[{'user_id': 1}, {'user_id': 2}, {'user_id': 3}, {'user_id': 4}, {'user_id': 5}]
```